# Issues with Strategy Pattern in c++

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance, strategy-pattern

i'm implementing a neural network with "LEARNING PURPOSES".

Y have the following templated classes:

- a Optimizer Base class with virtual method update taking a Parameter class reference as argument
- a Parameter class that contains the weights and bias, and that needs to call the update method of the optimizer
- a Linear class that stores information in the Parameter class
- a SGD class that inherits from Optimizer Base class (Strategy Pattern) where I override the update method.

The problem is that Parameter class is templated, and when passing it as a reference to de update method of the optimizer the compiler complains that the virtual method cannot be templated, and if I pass it as non templated, it complains that it doesn't have any templated parameters.

Also tried CRTP idiom for making Strategy Pattern static, so I can pass templated arguments to the virtual method, but the problem is that the compiler complains that the base class that i'm passing to the pointer where I store the optimizer in the Parameter should be templated.

```
#include<iostream>
  using size_type = std::size_t;
#include<vector>
#include<random>
#include<memory>

// #include "tensor_algebra.h"  here I define alias for Tensor operations
// for avoid using global namespaces
// but for testig you can use the following include

#include <Fastor/Fastor.h>
using namespace Fastor;

template<size_type input_features, size_type output_features>
struct Parameters;

class Optimizer{
  public:
    virtual void update(Parameters& parameters) = 0;
    virtual ~Optimizer() = default;
};

template<size_type input_features, size_type output_features>
struct Parameters{
    Tensor<float, input_features, output_features> weight;
    Tensor<float, input_features, output_features> weight_gradient;
    Tensor<float, output_features> bias;
    Tensor<float, output_features> bias_gradient;


    Parameters(const std::string& initializer = "he")
    : bias(0,0) {

      std::random_device rd;
      std::mt19937 generator(rd());
      std::normal_distribution<float> distribution;

      switch(initializer){
        case "he":
          distribution = std::normal_distribution<float>(0, std::sqrt(2.0 / input_features));
        break;

        case "xavier":
          distribution = std::normal_distribution<float>(0, std::sqrt(2.0 / input_features + output_features));  
        break;

        default:
          std::cout << "Invalid initializer" << std::endl;
        break;
      }

      for(auto i = 0; i < input_features; ++i){
        for(auto j = 0; j < output_features; ++j){
          weight(i, j) = distribution(generator);
        }
      }
    }

    void update(){
      optimizer->update(*this);
    }
};


class SGD : public Optimizer{
  public:
    SGD(float learning_rate) : learning_rate_(learning_rate) {}

    void update(Parameters& parameters){
      parameters.weight -= learning_rate_ * parameters.weight_gradient;
      parameters.bias -= learning_rate_ * parameters.bias_gradient;
    }

  private:
    float learning_rate_;
};

//Linear layer class

template<size_type input_features, size_type output_features>
class Linear{
  public:

    Linear(float learning_rate, const std::string& initializer = "he")
      : parameters(learning_rate, initializer){}
        
    void set_optimizer(std::shared_ptr<Optimizer> optimizer){
      parameters.optimizer = optimizer;
    } //Seting optimizer in linear layer.

    //forward method
    template<size_type batch_size>
    Tensor<float, batch_size, output_features> forward(const Tensor<float, batch_size, input_features> &input){
      Tensor<float,batch_size> ones(1);
      return matmul(input, parameters.weight) + outer(ones, parameters.bias); 
    }
  
    //backward method
    template<size_type batch_size>
    Tensor<float, batch_size, input_features> backward(
      const Tensor<float, batch_size, output_features> &gradient,
      const Tensor<float, batch_size, input_features>& input
    ){
      parameters.weight_gradient = matmul(transpose(input), gradient);
      parameters.bias_gradient = 0.0; // Initialize bias_gradient with zeros
      
      for (size_t i = 0; i < batch_size; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < output_features; j++){
        parameters.bias_gradient(j) += gradient(i, j);
        }
      }

      Tensor<float, batch_size, input_features> input_gradient = matmul(gradient, transpose(parameters.weight));
      return input_gradient;
    }
  
  private:
    Parameters<input_features, output_features> parameters;
};


int main(){
  Linear<2,3> linear(0.01);
  linear.set_optimizer(std::make_shared<SGD>(0.01));
  Tensor<float, 2, 2> input = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
  Tensor<float, 2, 3> output = linear.forward(input);
  std::cout << output << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I tried this:

```
template<class Derived>
class Optimizer{
  public:
    Derived& self(){return static_cast<Derived&>(*this);}
    const Derived& self() const {return static_cast<const Derived&>(*this);}

    template<size_type input_size, size_type output_size>
    void update(Parameters<input_size,output_size>& parameters){
      self().update(parameters);
    }
};

class SGD : public Optimizer<SGD>{
  public:
    SGD(float learning_rate) : learning_rate_(learning_rate) {}

    template<size_type input_size, size_type output_size>
    void update(Parameters<input_size,output_size>& parameters){
      parameters.weight -= learning_rate_ * parameters.weight_gradient;
      parameters.bias -= learning_rate_ * parameters.bias_gradient;
    }

  private:
    float learning_rate_;
};
```

but doesn't seems to work. Any advice?

Comment: Do you need runtime polymorphism or only compile time ?

Comment: I'm not optimizing the code yet so doesn't matter, I tried compile time polymorphism because of the templated parameters, virtual methods don't allow templated parameters in their arguments, and with static polymorphism i can pass a templated parameters, this is my first project so I don´t have to much experience with polymorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot understand what you really want to do because your code has many syntax errors, no call of `Parameters::update()`.

However I tried something to remove syntax errors, and to call `Parameters::update()` from `Linear`.
What I did is just simply making all classes to be template samely.
I hope it will be of some help.

Note: I don't have unkowns "Fastor.h", so, following code becames skelton like( all unknown type data and process for them ware simply removed.)

```cpp
template<size_type input_features, size_type output_features>
struct Parameters;

template<size_type input_features, size_type output_features>
class Optimizer{
public:
    virtual void update( Parameters<input_features,output_features>& parameters ) = 0;
    virtual ~Optimizer() = default;
};

template<size_type input_features, size_type output_features>
struct Parameters
{
    std::shared_ptr< Optimizer<input_features,output_features> > optimizer;

    Parameters(const std::string& initializer = "he"){  /*NOP*/ }
    void update(){  optimizer->update(*this);   }
};

template<size_type input_features, size_type output_features>
class SGD : public Optimizer<input_features, output_features>
{
public:
    SGD(float learning_rate) : learning_rate_(learning_rate) {}

    void update( Parameters<input_features,output_features> &parameters )
    {   std::cout << "SGD::update() called" << std::endl;   }

private:
    float learning_rate_;
};

//Linear layer class
template<size_type input_features, size_type output_features>
class Linear{
public:
    Linear( float learning_rate, const std::string& initializer = "he")
        : parameters( /*learning_rate,*/ initializer){}

    void set_optimizer( std::shared_ptr< Optimizer<input_features,output_features> > optimizer )
    {   parameters.optimizer = optimizer;   }

    //Test method I added
    void DoSomething(){ parameters.update();    }

private:
    Parameters<input_features, output_features> parameters;
};


int main(){
    Linear<2,3> linear(0.01f);
    linear.set_optimizer( std::make_shared< SGD<2,3> >(0.01f) );
    linear.DoSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I just tried that and in theory works, but the problem is that I will have to create an optimizer with different template parameters for every layer of the neural network, I will need some design pattern where I can tell my program, I want a SGD optimizer for every layer, or something like this, thanks anyway.

Comment: I think I will go with that for now, and then I will create a function to apply an optimizer to all the layers i pass to it. Thank you.

Comment: Since I have no knowledge about detail of neural network, I cannot say what is better...
however, implementing the non-template version may be helpful step, I think.

Comment: Also, I guess, such implementation that allow dynamically changing parameter values may be useful in finding final parameter values (:template parameter values).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::variant` for that.

Here is [a simplified example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8486360ec4ddc527):

```
int main(){
  Foo foo;
  foo.set_strategy(StrategyFactory::create<Strategy1>());
  foo.bar<int>();
  foo.bar<double>();
  foo.set_strategy(StrategyFactory::create<Strategy2>());
  foo.bar<int>();
  foo.bar<double>();
}
```

With the following:

```
struct Strategy1 {
    template<typename T>
    void bar() const {
        T t = 1;
        std::cout << t/2 << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Strategy2 {
    template<typename T>
    void bar() const {
        T t = 7;
        std::cout << t/2 << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And class Strategy, no inheritance is required:

```
class Strategy {
    friend class StrategyFactory; // See below
    using StrategyVariant = std::variant<Strategy1, Strategy2>;
    Strategy(StrategyVariant strategy)
        : strategy(std::move(strategy)) {}
    StrategyVariant strategy;
public:
    Strategy() {}
    template<typename T>
    void bar() {
      // the magic is here, using std::visit
      std::visit([](const auto& s) { s.template bar<T>(); }, strategy);
    }
};
```

To encapsulate the implementation details (e.g. that we use a variant) we can have a factory for creating the Strategy:

```
struct StrategyFactory {
    template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    static Strategy create(Ts&&... args) {
        return Strategy(T(std::forward<Ts>(args)...));
    }
};
```

And here we actually hold and use the Strategy:

```
class Foo {
    Strategy strategy; 
public:
    Foo() {}
    void set_strategy(Strategy s) { strategy = std::move(s); }
    template<typename T>
    void bar() {
        strategy.bar<T>();
    }
};
```